# javascriptでwidgets.js(外部の.jsファイル)読み込み完了を検知するには？

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, twitter, gatsby

gatsby.jsで製作中のサイトにTwitterのツイートを埋め込もうとしています。

htmlの`<head>`で
`<script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>`
を読み込んでいてるのですが、どうすればこれの読み込み完了をjavascriptで検知できるでしょうか？

```
const [tweetId, setTweetId] = useState()

useEffect(() => {
  const container = document.getElementById("container")
  window.twttr.widgets.createTweet(tweetId, container)
}, [tweetId])

setTweetId(12345)
```

上記のようなコードで、ページにツイートを埋め込んでいるのですが、「`window.twttr`が存在しません」みたいなエラーになります。

`window.twttr`というのは`widgets.js`がロード完了すると使えるようになる何かです。
（DOMなのか何なのか理解していません。誰か知っていたら教えてください。）

1. トップページ（ツイートを埋め込んでいない）にアクセスして、`widgets.js`を読み込ませる。
2. サブページ（ツイートを埋め込んでいる）に移動。
   のような手順ならエラーになりません。ツイートが画面に表示されます。

widgets.jsさえ読み込めればツイートを表示できているので、`window.twttr.widgets.createTweet()`の部分のコード自体が間違っている訳ではないです。

いまのところ、`setInterval`で1秒ごとに`window.twttr`の存在確認をしているのですが、効率が悪いと感じています。

`addEventListener`などで`window.twttr`が利用可能になるまで待ち、`window.twttr.widgets.createTweet()`を実行させるにはどうすればいいでしょうか？

Comment: これらの記事あたりでしょうか。["Load" event on script with async and/or defer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40193553/9014308), [Javascript: Is there any way to detect when all async scripts have loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32383398/9014308), [<script> タグに async / defer を付けた場合のタイミング](https://qiita.com/phanect/items/82c85ea4b8f9c373d684)

Comment: 標準的な仕様にはそういう物は無いのでは？ `widgets.js`のロードが完了した時にしか存在しない何かを定期的にチェックしてみるとかの工夫を考えるか、そもそもそういう個々のスクリプトファイルがロードされた時点を知る必要が無い処理や仕組みを考えてみては？

Comment: 目指す所が違うのかもしれませんが、こんなのでは駄目なのですか？ [GatsbyJS向けTweet投稿組み込みプラグイン2種、plugin or remark-plugin](https://irimasu.com/gatsbyjs-tweet-two-plugin-or-remark-plugin), [【GatsbyJS】ブログの記事にTwitterの投稿を埋め込んだ](https://rpf-noblog.com/2020-07-07/gatsby-twitter/), [GatsbyでYouTubeとTwitter埋め込み](https://takumon.com/2018/10/07/)

Comment: 回答しているのではなく、[XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2701/26370) のような気がするので色々な方向から考えた方が良いのでは、と思ってコメントしています。こんな記事とかもあるようですね。[公式ドキュメントで紹介されているスニペットを活用する - JSでツイートを埋め込むときのベストプラクティス](https://zenn.dev/catnose99/articles/329d7d61968efb#%E5%85%AC%E5%BC%8F%E3%83%89%E3%82%AD%E3%83%A5%E3%83%A1%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E3%81%A7%E7%B4%B9%E4%BB%8B%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B%E3%82%B9%E3%83%8B%E3%83%9A%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%82%92%E6%B4%BB%E7%94%A8%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)

Comment: [JavaScript to detect when external javascripts are loading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8718354) が要求に適うかどうかは判りませんが、http://jsfiddle.net/8cskuem7/ で試す限りは動作する様です(`async=true` の設定が効いているかどうかは不明)。

Comment: MDNにあったこれ [例#1: スクリプトを動的にインポートする](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement#%E4%BE%8B1_%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AA%E3%83%97%E3%83%88%E3%82%92%E5%8B%95%E7%9A%84%E3%81%AB%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%83%9D%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B) とかですかね。「非同期的に実行される」と書いてあります。他にこれとか。[リソース読み込み: onload と onerror](https://ja.javascript.info/onload-onerror) こちらは非同期に出来るかどうかは書いて無いですが。

Comment: @kunif さん、@metropolis さん、回答はコメントではなく回答としてご投稿ください。コメントはあくまで質問を改善していくための「付箋」のようなもので、いつでも削除されえます。役に立つ Q&A を蓄積していくためにも回答としての投稿をお願いいたします。

Comment: 私の方は浅薄な思い込みで場を乱していただけのようです。正確な知識・経験があるわけでは無いので、このままとしておきます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter Developer Platformでは、「最も信頼できる方法」としてwidgets.jsロード用のサンプルコードが紹介されています。
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/javascript-api/guides/set-up-twitter-for-websites

```js
<script>window.twttr = (function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    t = window.twttr || {};
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return t;
  js = d.createElement(s);
  js.id = id;
  js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

  t._e = [];
  t.ready = function(f) {
    t._e.push(f);
  };

  return t;
}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));</script>
```

このように`widgets.js`をロードした後、`twttr.ready`関数の引数にロード完了後実行したいコールバック関数またはアロー関数を投入すればツイートが表示されます。

```js
    twttr.ready( () => twttr.widgets.createTweet("20",document.querySelector('div.container'))) ;
```

ここまでがリンク先のドキュメントに記載されいてる内容です。

質問のようなコードの場面で使用するのであれば、`twttr.ready`関数の引数に`setTweetId`を実行するコールバック関数を設定すれば表示できるのではないかと思います。

Comment: 紹介いただいたサンプルコードに
`t.ready(() => {
console.log("widgets.jsロード完了")
})`
を追加し、`widget.js`の読み込み完了時にログが記録されることを確認。

`createTweet`の実行タイミングを`twttr.ready`で調整すれば当初の目的を達成できそうです。
ご回答ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

ごく素直に、対象の`script`要素の`load`イベントで検知できるはずです。

Comment: metropolisさんが作ってくれたサンプルで動いてますし、私も動作することを確認しました。

Comment: metropolisさんのjsfiddleのサンプルをそのまま書けば、gatsby.js上でも動作しました！
前回の失敗の原因は、react-helmetでheadに`<script id='xxx' async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>`を追加していたせいでした。
`const script = document.getElementById('xxx'); script.addEventListener()`の時点ではscriptタグ自体がまだ生成されていなかったみたい。
`document.createElement('script'`)から`adEventListener`までの流れを1か所でまとめて設定すればちゃんと動きました。